# Check 3 columns in 3 different dataframes and create a new column

Tags: python, dataframe

I have three dataframes like this

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | row |

All the dataframe have ID column in common. There is a main dataframe against which the other two needs to be compared.
Logic I want to implement:

1. if ID's of second dataframe matches with the first, then create a column and give it a constant 'A' value.
2. if ID's of third dataframe matches with the first, in the same column  give it a constant 'B' value.
3. if it doesn't appear in either of them,in the same column  give it a constant 'I'

I am trying to make it efficient instead of creating two for loops. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried and what went wrong with your attempts? For example, `merge()`, `isin()`, `where()` all might be good methods to start with. If you [edit] to include a [mcve] it might help us to understand your problem, with samples of your inputs dataframes and the expected output based on those inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what it appears you want:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1, 2, 3],
    'name': [
        "read the documentation",
        "check your question hasn't been asked before",
        "create an MRE"
    ]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1],
    'url': ["http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/"]
})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [2],
    'url': ["https://stackoverflow.com/search"]
})

df1['new_col'] = df1['ID'].apply(lambda x: 'A' if x in df2['ID'].values else 'B' if x in df3['ID'].values else 'I')

# Output:
   ID                                          name new_col
0   1                        read the documentation       A
1   2  check your question hasn't been asked before       B
2   3                                 create an MRE       I
```